# How to make Drupal Commerce tokens available in the Commerce Message module?

Tags: 7, commerce, tokens, message-subscribe

In addition to the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module, I installed the [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module for Drupal 7. Everything works fine so far.

I created a new Rule to send a billing e-mail in addition to the order completed e-mail to the customer.

But now I have the problem that I can not apply any tokens that give me the address or full name of the customer. It seems, that the standard [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) tokens do not work in the [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module.

I looked through the files of [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) and I can only find a few tokens that do not help at all.

According to law I need to send billing information to the customer. Including the customer's full name and address.

How can I use the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) standard tokens with [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message)?

Also despite saying that it would be able to use multiple html tags it does not. Whenever I use `<em>` (for example: `<em>italic</em>`) it does not include such `<em>` in the e-mail (for example: it only includes  `/italic/`).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your question is about the "Commerce Message" module, at its core your question relates to the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. And since you are using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, you can make the missing tokens (= *the commerce standard tokens*, as in your question ...) available by using the Replacement patterns for each message type.

So the answer to your question is "***Whatever token you're missing, just make it available via Rules, by creating a replacement token for them***". Refer to the answer to [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/109) for way more details on that.

These *Replacement tokens* are really a hidden gem about how Rules integrates with Message. For an example to see them at work, refer to my answer to "[Which user related token(s) can be used to create a Rule for setting up a message type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/219680/39516)".

Answer (score 0):

About this part of your question (near the end):

> ... use multiple html tags ...

That's really a different question, so here is a separated answer to that also: it must be that for the "Message text" you're using, you're using an HTML filter in which the `<em>` tag is not allowed (yet). So make sure to use an HTML filter in which it is allowed.

Comment: The strange things is that I use FULL HTML Filter for that.
It just doesn't seem to be the filter that is applied.
For now I used a workaround concerning the html problem.