# How to include order details in eMail notifications created with the Message module?

Tags: commerce, notifications, message-subscribe

I am working with placing an order with the Commerce module in Drupal. When the order is confirmed, a notification will be send to the user with order details. Here I am using a rule like when an order is confirmed, customer will receive an email.

The email content will be from the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module based on the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Also there is a content from the Commerce module regarding order details.

My doubt is that how to get this order details content from the Commerce module to this Message module content.

Below is the mail content that I saw in the backend when the rule is applied. But the content doesn't have any order details. But when the mail is received order details are present. I want to find out how to get these order details along with this content.

> Dear [message:message-commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing:commerce-customer-address:first_name], Thank you for purchasing through [site:name]. You can view your order history by logging into our website at:[message:message-commerce-order:view-url] Sincerely, Order Number: [message:message-commerce-order:order-number]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Part 1: About the concept of using Replacement tokens

By using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, you should be able to make any relevant token concerning the `order details content` (as in your question ...) available by using the Replacement patterns for each message type created with the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module.

So the answer to your question is "***Whatever token you're missing, just make it available via Rules, by creating a replacement token for them***". Refer to the answer to [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/109) for way more details on that.

These *Replacement tokens* are really a hidden gem about how Rules integrates with Message. For an example to see them at work, refer to my answer to "[Which user related token(s) can be used to create a Rule for setting up a message type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/219680/39516)".

## Part 2: Including some order detail in your message type

#### 1. Scenario

Let's assume you want allow the user to enter some (custom) order detail. I.e. let's just call it "order remark" (some free format text, which any customer can use for whatever they want).

We want the related order confirmation message (actually an eMail) to have an eMail subject that includes the value of the free format text entered as "order remark".

Read on for the steps needed to get this to work ... Starting from a vanilla "Commerce Kickstart" installation.

#### 2. Add an additional order field

Use relative path `admin/commerce/config/order/fields` to add another (custom) field within "Order settings". In my case, I use a text field, with machine name `field_order_remark`.

#### 3. Define a replacement token

Use relative path `admin/structure/messages/manage/commerce_order_order_confirmation` to *edit* the configuration of Message type "Commerce Order: order confirmation". Within the field labelled "Replacement tokens", enter something similar to `@remark_related_to_order` (= this will be the name of the token we want to use / populate in the next step).

On the same (Message type) form, you can start to use (= refer to) this replacement token, and this anywhere you want to do so. As a sample, I just added `(remark: @remark_related_to_order)` at the end of the eMail subject (within the Message Text labelled "View modes: Notify - Email subject").

#### 4. Custom rule

The only thing left, is to create an appropriate rule (or tune an existing rule), so that when a Message is created (of type "Commerce Order: order confirmation"), a value is assigned to the replacement token `@remark_related_to_order`, whereas the actual value is the value entered for the (custom) order field with machine name `field_order_remark`.

To do so, just consider the rule below (in Rules export format):

```
{ "rules_commerce_order_message_order_notification" : {
    "LABEL" : "Commerce order message: order notification e-mail",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "3",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "message_notify", "commerce_checkout" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ], "field" : "field_order_remark" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "message",
            "param_type" : "commerce_order_order_confirmation",
            "param_user" : [ "commerce-order:owner" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:message-commerce-order" ],
          "value" : [ "commerce-order" ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:arguments:remark-related-to-order" ],
          "value" : [ "commerce-order:field-order-remark" ]
        }
      },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-created" ], "immediate" : 1 } },
      { "message_notify_process" : {
          "message" : [ "entity-created" ],
          "save_on_fail" : 0,
          "save_on_success" : 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above rule is actually a minor variation of the same named rule shipped with Commerce Kickstart, in which these are the specific changes I applied to get it to work:

- the extra Rules Condition "Entity has field". This is to make rules aware of the (custom) order field with machine name `field_order_remark`. And so that we can refer to it in a subsequent Rules Action.
- the extra Rules Action to "Set a data value". I.e. for the replacement token `remark_related_to_order`, whereas the actual value is the value entered for the (custom) order field with machine name `field_order_remark`. Note the special syntax used for that `entity-created:arguments:remark-related-to-order`

***Voilà***, that's really it. Just repeat the steps above for any other "order detail" you want to be processed in a similar way (each of them will require an additional replacement token, and the rule will have to assign an appropriate value using some order related token.

PS: I'm assuming your question is about D7.

Comment: Can we add custom template for this message?Especially for that token section commerce module regarding order details?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that custom template. Please EDIT your question to add an export of a rule that has a rules action to show a drupal system message in which you show 1 of the order details. I will then try to improve my answer to use that as a replacement token.

Comment: BELOW IS THE MAIL CONTENT THAT I SAW IN THE BACKEND WHEN APPLIED THE RULE.BUT THE CONTENT DOESNT HAVING ANY ORDER DETAILS.BUT WHEN THE MAIL IS RECEIVED ORDER DETAILS ARE PRESENT.I WANT TO FIND OUT HOW TO GET THIS ORDER DETAILS ALONG WITH THIS CONTENT.CAN YOU HELP ME? 
Dear [message:message-commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing:commerce-customer-address:first_name], Thank you for purchasing  through [site:name]. Yyou can view your order history by logging into our website at:[message:message-commerce-order:view-url]  Sincerely, Order Number: [message:message-commerce-order:order-number]

Comment: sorry am not getting what you are saying

Comment: @user3487918: writing entire phrases with all uppercases is commonly perceived as "yelling". Also, your original question includes "based on Rules" (which is indeed the way to dowhat you try to achieve). But you still didn't mention at least "*1 of the order details*" you want to use/include in your message type. If I may ask: did you already carefully review/study the content of those 2 links in my answer? Trust me: the solution for your question will be similar. But if you don't mention at least 1 order detail you wonder about, I cannot improve my answer to teach you about that one. Get it?

Comment: Hello,thanks for your reply.I got the order detail field in my case.There is a views from commerce module called "commerce_cart_summary".When i passed the order id i got the order details regarding that.This view is in the table format and it is used in the commerce_message.module(My guess is, the order details are processed from this views).What is my real issue is when send the notification email to gmail,yahoo and outlook,the design of "order details section" is totally different.In yahoo and outlook mails the design is totally broken.Can you give me any suggestion for that??

Answer (score 1):

You just goto 
http://localhost/project/admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules/manage/commerce_checkout_order_email/edit/3

[image]

then as screenshot into the message value you can set your custom message and also use "Replacement patterns" for order detail to the message.

thank you..

Comment: Can we add  custom template to this message ?? Especially that token from commerce module? Any hooks for that?

Comment: Also try hook_mail_alter()..  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7.x

Comment: Hello thanks for your help.Because i got the  reference field message_commerce_order based on your suggestion.Thanks a lot.The data referred by "message_commerce_order"  is order details.This content is in table format.Then how to find out how this data is calculated?